# Visual Studio layouts aren't saved

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2013, layout

As far as I know, Visual Studio must save layouts for, e.g., `Edit` and `Debug` modes apart from each other.

But that's not the case. Toolbars I switch on/off in `Edit` are transitioned to `Debug` and vice versa. Only *Debug*, *Debug Location* and *Application Insights* toolbars' statuses are saved. May be some others too, I didn't check all of them, but about a half of all, just those that I use, mostly.

Windows layouts are saved as intended, though.

I've reset Environment Settings a couple of times and experimented with opening/closing VS in different modes, but still no signs of solution.

Comment: *As far as I know, Visual Studio must save layouts for, e.g., Edit and Debug modes apart from each other.* - What makes you think that?

Comment: @Ramhound wow, your question takes me by surprise.. i don't know why i think that, actually o_O. but that makes no sense: saving windows in layouts, but not saving toolbars? what kind of user-friendlyness is that! besides, there actually are toolboxes that save their state between layouts.

Comment: Previous versions of Visual Studio were a little different in their behavior between Edit and Debug modes which is the reason I asked.